# Javascript Option element's Select in IE Compatibility

Tags: javascript

I am creating a option control in javascript dynamically:

I populate the options from an ajax call's return object.

I check my result object for a default flag, and set the dom object "select"'s "selected" attribute.

This works fine, except for in Compatibility mode the result is not the same.

In IE Compatability Mode (IE  7) the option has the first select value indexed.

```
select = document.createElement("select");
                select.id = "tr_theGrid" + i + "_DropDown";
                select.className = "theField"
                select.style.width = "100%";

                for (var x = 0; x < docpreviews.length; x++) {

                    option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.value = docpreviews[x].PrevId;
                    option.innerHTML = docpreviews[x].PrevName;

                    if (m_documents_Merge.DocumentsAttachments[i].Previews[x].Selected == "1") {

                        option.defaultSelected = true;

                    }

                    select.appendChild(option);

                }
```

This works fine outside IE, why does IE compatibility mode not recognize this as a selected option?

Comment: Why not just `option.selected`?

Comment: I used option.setAttribute("selected", "selected"); and it seems to be working in compatability as well as non.  Is this the correct way I should be doing this?  If it works it works right:P

Comment: Yeah - you can just do `option.selected` as well - both will do the same.

Comment: To set the value of an option, set its *text* property: `option.text = ...` or append a text node. Options don't contain markup so it's not appropriate to set the *innerHTML* property, though browsers allow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be setting the `selected` property of the `option` element:

```
if (m_documents_Merge.DocumentsAttachments[i].Previews[x].Selected == "1") {
    option.selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [*Option constructor*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement.Option) to create options:

```
for (var x = 0; x < docpreviews.length; x++) {

    // new Option([text[, value[, defaultSelected[, selected]]]])
    option = new Option(docpreviews[x].PrevName, docpreviews[x].PrevId);

    if (m_documents_Merge.DocumentsAttachments[i].Previews[x].Selected == "1") {

        // To make the option selected, but does not make it the default selected option
        option.selected = true;

        // To make the option the default selected, but does not make it selected
        option.setAttribute('selected', true);
    }
    select.appendChild(option);
}
```

Setting the *selected* **property** to true makes the option selected but does not make it the default selected option, i.e., resetting the form will not set that option to selected.

Setting the *selected* **attribute** sets the option to be the default selected option, i.e. if the form is reset, the option is selected, but does not make it the currently selected option.

If you want the option to be selected and be the default selected option, set both the attribute and property.

The *defaultSelected* property is read only in some browsers and can't be set, though some allow it.